# Silverlight App (MVVM ) + Unity Issue

Tags: silverlight, unity-container

I have teh following scenario:
OrderListViewModel, serving a list of Orders to OrderListView view in OrderListView the selected Order get stored in SelectdOrder property of the OrderListViewModel, so when a user want to see the details of the order he select an Order from a list and navigate to the OrderDetail page

```
//OrderListViewModel code
public void ShowOrder(){
    this.unityContainer.RegisterInstance(Order, new ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager());
    //Code to navigate tothe detail page
    NavigationService.Navigate("/Order/OrderView");
}
```

Then i have OrderViewModel, and in its constructor:

```
public OrderViewModel(){
    order = unityContainer.Resolve<PedidoCompra>();
}
```

Now the issue i get is that in some situation i get and exception with this message:
The value cannot be null. Parameter name : instance

When i access the site from my local network ( the hosting server is at officce ) it behave well but when i access the site from internet then is when it get the previous error.
Someome have come accross of this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a guess based on the posted behavior plus some extrapolation.

Sounds like `Order` is populated using a web service/remote call.  Sometimes when you go to register the instance with Unity the remote call has not returned yet (since the call executes asynchronously).  Or perhaps it did not return an instance (e.g. possible error, etc.) but I suspect it's timing.

The reason why it works on the local network and not on the internet is that the response time of the local network is much faster than the internet. The remote call returns very quickly over the local network so `Order` is usually not null.

Comment: Hi Tuzo,the environment is a Silverlight application using Ria Service, i get your point but in this scenario Order is loaded in the List so at the time to show the detail in the Detail page no server query is performed, so in the list view model the Order instance is stored to Unity container to get injected into the Detail View Model, just that
Thanks

Comment: OK.  But the problem is still that you are trying to Register a null instance (that's what the exception indicates).  You need to find out why it is null.